# How to crop featured image in different sizes?

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

I have a Wordpress theme which require 4 images sizes:

- small: 960x535
- medium: 1380x770
- large: 1920x1071
- full: 2240x1361

Is there a way to crop the featured image into these sizes so I can use them in my PHP and HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define other sizes with [this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

Comment: I was told I could not use this function because a user needs to select the size they want to use and I basically need all of 'em

Comment: Please post a proper answer. Use [answer] as a guide to help you

Comment: I assume user need to have option to select the size while inserting image using Media Library, in that case: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-custom-images-sizes-to-the-wordpress-media-library/

Comment: @rzepak so that blog says the image sizes are already created with these sizes by default, hmm I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
add_image_size ('new-name', 220, 180, true);
```

in your functions.php file and use

```
the_post_thumbnail ('new-name');
```

where you want cropped image. This will give you image of size 220x180 size image.